# how to check parse particular filed data updated on cloud side.

Tags: android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

**I want to implement cloud code on parse. I have user class in parse and have some custom column like approve or not.**

**Now i have admin side app have functionality to give approve that user.i have admin side fragment with ApproveUser  which show all details of user then have one button of approve**

**Now i want to click it and change value in column approveornot of user class.**

**Now i also want to send push notification to that user which was admin approve**

**How can i do this.**

I know using cloud code we do this but exactly how can i do. aftersave method how can i check that particular user field is update then i write code  for push send.

Comment: Parse.com is shutting down soon so it would be better not make your app use parse for server side programming

Comment: @VivekMishra so what is alternate way for it. i am using parse for my backend.so after this year it will not work.???

Comment: http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/ check this link

Comment: @VivekMishra I know that but i am looking same like parse which provide all features.its provide tools for migrating.but in that db is in other place server is other so. now i am just start new app based on parse .so i am think for other platform .

Answer (score 0):

You must be having an object of ParseUser if you are showing its detail. So when you want to change the value of on of its column you should code something like:

```
ParseUser user;
user.put("column_name","value")
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        System.out.println("updated");
                    }
                });
```

And to check if the value is updated or not you can log on to Parse and go to core option and check user table there.

Comment: dear I know that but how to implement  it. how to target particular user for push. mean if admin approve whatever person push notification will send to that person.